# moved site folder and now getting Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header()

Tags: wordpress, fatal-error

I copied a folder (named FitWP) from a co-workers "My Web Sites" folder to my "My Web Sites" folder on my local computer. I believe that folder only contained the theme; header, index, footer, all of those pages. I have a separate folder (named Fit2Work)  that i believe is part of the original site, that folder contains; index, wp-config, wp-signup, etc., all of those pages. When I try to Run the site (the folder named FitWP) i get the "Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header()" error. I've looked around and seen that one suggestion is that i dont have WP installed but i dont know where to install it, i'm using WebMatrix so I just originally would create a site from the Template Gallery and that would install WP for me. I've never installed it by hand or had to do what i'm doing today, trying to retrieve someones site that was taken down due to nonpayment. I dont know how to get the site up and running now and the client needs it.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. How to repair your website is offtopic.

Comment: This question is already posted in Stack Overflow, maybe worded differently but it is a programming issue of sorts to other people except the "fixes" I found didn't work for me. I've looked everywhere and found nothing so i decided to post here and wish for the best. You can help if you want but that comment did nothing for me or anyone else. You can redirect me to where to post or just not comment at all. I just need some sort of help, anything!